# How to progressively increase the number of animated DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to animate a div box for several times when a button is pressed. It shall go right, and again right, then it comes a bit down and the text inside should change, and then it shall go left, and again left to its original place. This is my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/LSegC/ Hopefully everything is fine now.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
  var d=$("#t");
  var number=$("#number1").val();
  var speed=2000;

//  if(state==true){
        d.animate({left:'+=230px'}, speed);
        d.animate({left:'+=230px'}, speed);
        d.animate({top:'+=20px', backgroundColor: "#f09090", text:'12'}, speed/4, "swing", function(){
            $('#span').fadeOut(500, function() {
                $(this).text('a1').fadeIn(500);
            });
        });
        d.delay(1000).animate({left:'-=230px'}, speed);
        d.animate({left:'-=230px'}, speed);
        d.fadeOut();

//        }
  });
});
```

Now what I want to know how to do is that when the steps above are finished, I want to increase the number of animated divs. So next time, I want TWO such divs following eachother to animate, and when they are done, then THREE of them should go, each showing its own number. Does anyone have any clues how to progressively increase the number of animated DIVs step by step?
-Thanks

Comment: I'm going to assume that the reason you code wrapped your link is because you got an error message saying that JSFiddle links should be accompanied with code. This means the code in which you are referring to in your problem should be here, in this question. It doesn't mean literally wrap your link in code marks.

Comment: ummm, I see! Yes, logically it should have been like that. Edited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you swithch to classes instead of id for `#t`, then it's easy. Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function() {

      var d = $(".t").fadeIn();
      var speed = +$("#number1").val();

      d.animate({left:'+=230px'}, speed);
      d.animate({left:'+=230px'}, speed);
      d.animate({top:'+=20px', backgroundColor: "#f09090", text:'12'}, speed/4, "swing", function() {
          $('.span', this).fadeOut(100, function() {
              $(this).text(function() {
                  return 'a' + $(this).text().replace('a', '');
              }).fadeIn(100);
          });
      });
      d.delay(1000).animate({left:'-=230px'}, speed);
      d.animate({left:'-=230px'}, speed);
      d.fadeOut().promise().done(function() {
          d.last().after(function() {

              var top = +$(this).css('top').replace('px', ''),
                  number = +$(this).data('number') + 1,
                  $clone = $(this).clone();

              $clone.data('number', number).css('top', top + 20);
              $clone.find('.span').text(number);

              return $clone;
          });

          d.find('.span').text(function() {
              return $(this).text().replace('a', '');
          });
      })
  });
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LSegC/1/

Comment: ummm, seems promising. I want to make it not linear increasing, but exponential increase, but it does not work. Like 1 packet, 2, 4, 8, ... I'm trying to put it in a loop, but don't work!